# Is there a uniform python library to transfer files using different protocols

Tags: python, file, ftp, networking, nfs

I know there is `ftplib` for ftp, `shutil` for local files, what about NFS? I know urllib2 can **get** files via HTTP/HTTPS/FTP/FTPS, but it can't **put** files.

If there is a uniform library that automatically detects the protocol (FTP/NFS/LOCAL) with URI and deals with file transfer (get/put) transparently, it's even better, does it exist?

Comment: Could you explain the use case for this?  How is it possible not to know in advance which protocol you're using?  What are the circumstances where this would be useful?

Comment: Simple: copy <file> <url> which works for any type of URL. I'd say that such a tool would come in handy for many uses. Right now, you have to use putty/scp, wget, ....

Comment: Except there's no "NFS://" scheme; would that be the same as "file://"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look up and use pycurl/libcurl. Libcurl: http://curl.haxx.se/ PyCurl: http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/ - curl supports the http://, file://, and ftp:// uris. I have used it with much success.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at KDE IOSlaves. They can manage all the protocol you describe, plus a few others (samba, ssh, ...).

You can instantiates IOSlaves through PyKDE or if that dependency is too big, you can probably manage the ioslave from python with the subprocess module.